# Как перезаписать файл при редактировании формы?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Помогите разобраться как перезаписать файл при редактировании формы? Добавление файла/удаление работает.

```
//добавление формы
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {

$type = $_POST['type'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$id_conf = $_POST['id_conf'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$time_test = $_POST['time_test'];
$time_start = $_POST['time_start'];
$time = strtotime($time_test);
$time_send = date("H:i", strtotime('-15 minutes', $time));

 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], 'upload/'.$_FILES['filename']['name']);
  $path = 'upload/'.$_FILES['filename']['name'];

$query = "INSERT INTO post SET type='$type', date='$date', time_test='$time_test', time_start='$time_start', time_send='$time_send', img='$path'";
mysqli_query($link, $query);
header('Location: main.php');
exit();
}

//редактирование формы
elseif (isset($_POST['edit'])) {
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $id_conf = $_POST['id_conf'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $time_test = $_POST['time_test'];
    $time_start = $_POST['time_start'];
    $time = strtotime($time_test);
    $time_send = date("H:i", strtotime('-15 minutes', $time));
    
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], 'upload/'.$_FILES['filename']['name']);
     $path = 'upload/'.$_FILES['filename']['name'];

    $query = "UPDATE post SET type='$type', date='$date', id_conf='$id_conf', pass='$pass', time_test='$time_test', time_start='$time_start', time_send='$time_send', img='$path' WHERE id='$_POST[id]'";
    mysqli_query($link, $query);
    header('Location: main.php');
    exit();
}
```

В итоге если вставляю в инпут при редактировании файл, он ничего не пишет а также из базы удаляет существующий.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: попробуйте заменить WHERE id='$_POST[id]' на WHERE id={$_POST['id']}

Comment: но подставлять значения из массива пост напрямую в sql-запрос нельзя, т.к. это возможность для злоумышленника внедрить вредоносный код. Рекомендую использовать подготавливаемые запросы https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php